# MySql: Using concat does not work, why?

Tags: mysql, substring, concatenation

I have this query:

```
update sales_flat_quote set customer_email = (concat(select substring(md5(rand()) from 1 for 20), '@example.com'));
```

It gives me this error: *3 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 SQL1.sql 6 1*. I want to concat the results from the substring select with the static @example.com string.

Whats wrong with the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select substring(md5(rand()) from 1 for 20` returns a result set, not a string.

The proper way to do what you want would be `update sales_flat_quote set customer_email = (concat(substring(md5(rand()) from 1 for 20), '@example.com'));`

Answer (score 1):

To use a subselect you have to enclose it within parenthesis:

```
update sales_flat_quote set customer_email = concat(
        (select substring(md5(rand()) from 1 for 20)), 
        '@example.com');
```

Note that in this case you don't need to use a subselect: `rand()` will be called for each row.